# Diet on Starting Strength - Should I eat the same on my rest days as on my workout days?

Tags: nutrition, starting-strength

[This link](http://www.startingstrengthtraining.com/diet/) gives a nice outline of the diet on a training day - but I can't find any reference to what one should eat on a rest day (i.e. since SS is a 3-day workout, what to eat on the other 4 days?)

Is it the same stuff minus the pre/post workout meals?

Answer (score 1):

You can take many approaches:

Eating the same on rest days will help you get bigger and stronger, but you might put on some fat with the muscle.

Taking the pre/post meals out as you suggest will promote "slower" progress, but should help it be "lean gainz."

Some would suggest altering carbohydrate levels on training/nontraining days, but that requires a bit more thinking. A great resource on this is Carb-Backloading by John Kiefer. I have been "backloading" for a while now and I like it a lot, as I have been able to adapt it to my training needs and current goals.

Hope this helps.

PS: I think that website is way behind on the "science" of performance nutrition. It would be wise for you to look into people like John Meadows and John Kiefer.

Adding links like poster asked in comments (no summaries):

EliteFTS article on CBL: http://articles.elitefts.com/nutrition/carb-back-loading/

John Kiefer's site: http://athlete.io/

John Meadows's site: http://mountaindogdiet.com/

Comment: Can you provide some links/references? Googling may take me elsewhere than you intended, hence the request!

Comment: See edit. Hope you find what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

On off days, eat just the same as your lifting days, just without pre- and post-workout meals. There are more complicated ways to approach things, but don't worry about it. The biggest change I make on non-lifting days is just to eat more and more frequently, since I don't have to worry about a full stomach during my workout.

Comment: Are the "more complicated ways" the same as those mentioned in @tannman357's answer?

Comment: There are many, many, many approaches, of which the approaches he mentions are a couple of.

Answer (score 0):

The article suggests getting most of your carbs throughout the day and than adding some pre-workout. If you do a normal sized high intensity workout, you will:

- Need to be carbed-upp prior to workout
- Replenish during workout

Both require a relative shitload of carbs, that you should probably get as 'fast' carbs from fruit and isotonic drinks. Given the amount of carbs taken this way on workout days, I would suggest that its probably best to make the rest of your work-out days basically low-carb. You can than get your low-sugar slow carbs (taters, pasta, rice, bread, etc) on resting day and have equal amounts of carbs every day. That is:

Workout day: get most of your carbs from fruit (fructose) and isotonic drinks (glucose) and time it to only be (pre-)workout.
Resting day: get most of your carbs from starches (vegies, taters, pasta, rice, bread, etc) and time it to spread it across all meals.